# Embed streams with private ip adress

Tags: .htaccess, routes, camera, apache2, raspbian

**Status quo**

I'm running apache2 on raspiban. I have created a web page. I would like to embed camera streams from motioneyeos as fast network camera. The cameras are located in my local network and are not accessible via the internet. Short, I would like a surveillance hub accessibile via the internet.

It should look like this:

```
<img src="http://192.168.0.53:8081/" alt="camera1">
```

**Problem**

The streams can't reached from outside of my home network.
How can I route the stream connection via the web server to access the camera?

**Approaches**

I tried routing with ReWrite in .htaccess like this

```
Redirect 301 /camera1/ http://192.168.0.53:8081
```

of course same Problem.

I don't want the camera streams public because I can't protect them with a password. Unlike the website.

Would be grateful for tips or links to similar problems/solutions.

Comment: A redirect of course has the same issue, because that's still causing your external client to make the request. You will need to proxy the request via your webserver. https://superuser.com/a/1285502

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try that :)